# Selenium element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I am trying to click on a close button to close a popup. However, I get the error `element not visible`. I am checking if the element exists in the page, but still the error comes up. The piece of code giving the error is

```
while(driver.findElements(By.className("ui_close_x")).size() < 0);
driver.findElements(By.className("ui_close_x")).get(0).click();
System.out.println("Clkd");
```

Where am I going wrong?

> Trying to crawl tripAdvisor

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: check the size of driver.findElements(By.className("ui_close_x")) - you can have more then one such element, and the first one (with index 0) can be not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("ui_close_x")));
elements.get(0).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly